# Multiprocessing Module Runs Slower with Worker Function?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to use Python's multiprocessing module to speed up processing. However, when I have run the test_parallel_compute function at the very bottom of the code, on a computing cluster with 32 nodes (**EDIT** I've found out that I'm only running across one node), the time for the program to run without multiprocessing is longer: 1024 seconds (32 processes) vs 231 seconds (no multiprocessing module used). 1022 of the seconds were spent in the pool.map call within the parallel_compute_new_2 function, so the time is not limited by partitioning the inputs nor by joining the return functions.

I have an input list (b) and several other arguments (a and c) to the function (test_function). In order to prepare these for the multiple processors, I partition b. I then give the function and its partitioned arguments as arguments to worker_function_new, which calls the test_function on its partitioned arguments.

**QUESTION EDITTED**:
Can you see any inefficiencies in mapping the multiple processes as below? Again, 1022 of the seconds were spent in the pool.map call within the parallel_compute_new_2 function, so the time is not limited by partitioning the inputs nor by joining the return functions.

I am calling running this with inputs of a = 100.0, b = range(10000000), and c = 15.0.

Thank you!

```
# Partition the input list
def partition_inputs(input, number):
    num_inputs = len(input)
    return [input[num_inputs * i/number:num_inputs * (i+1)/number] for i in range(number)]

# This is the function that each process is supposed to run.
# It takes in several arguments. b is a long list, which is partitioned
# into multiple slices for each process. a and c are just other numbers.
# This function's return values, d, e, and f, are joined between each process.
def test_function_2(args):
    a = args[0]
    b = args[1]
    c = args[2]
    d = []
    e = 0
    f = {}
    for i in b:
        d.append(a*i*c)
        f[i] = set([a, i, c])
    return d, e, f



def parallel_compute_new_2(function, args, input, input_index, partition_input_function, join_functions_dict, pool,
                     number=32, procnumber=32):
    # Partition the b list. In my case, the partition_input_function is
    # partition_input_list, as above.

    new_inputs = partition_input_function(input, number)

    # Since test_function_2 requires arguments (a, c) beyond the partitioned
    # list b, create a list of the complete arguments. 
    worker_function_args_list = []
    for i in range(number):
        new_args = args[:]
        new_args[input_index] = new_inputs[i]
        worker_function_args_list.append(new_args)

    returnlist = pool.map(function, worker_function_args_list)

    # Join the return values from each process.
    return_values = list(returnlist[0])

    for index in join_functions_dict:
        for proc in range(1, number):
            return_values[index] = join_functions_dict[index](return_values[index], returnlist[proc][index])

    return return_values

def test_parallel_compute(a, b, c, number=32, procnumber=32):


    join_functions_dict = {}
    join_functions_dict[0] = lambda a, b: a + b
    join_functions_dict[2] = combine_dictionaries

    # a = 100.
    # b = range(1000000000)
    # c = 15.

    d, e, f = test_function(a, b, c)

    pool = mup.Pool(processes=procnumber)

    d1, e1, f1 = parallel_compute_new_2(test_function_2, [a, b, c], b, 1, partition_inputs, join_functions_dict, pool, number=number, procnumber=procnumber)
```

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it. Would you happen to have any insight on the possible problem here?

Comment: Can you clarify what your partition input function does? And are you sure that the processes are actually running across all the nodes in the cluster, or are they just focused on one node?

Comment: Might be related to/solved by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727375/multiprocessing-pool-slower-than-just-using-ordinary-functions?rq=1

Comment: EDIT: Sorry about this! I found out I am only running over one processor and one node right now. Let me run over multiple processors and I'll see if the problem persists.