# why the multiprocessing stops

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

I have followed the code in the link [multiprocessing.Pool() slower than just using ordinary functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727375/multiprocessing-pool-slower-than-just-using-ordinary-functions) to write a multi process program, but I find when the length of data in **mainwordlist** is relatively large, the code can't work. (you can try by setting **xrange(50)** to **xrange(1000)** in the code)

Actually, the terminal interface shows that the code is still running, however, the process in top command is gone, can anyone tell me why? any comment will be appreciated. thank you!
[image: terminal interface][image: process in top command]

Comment: I think they are sleeping, but I still don't know why

Answer (score 0):

I find the following link http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/16/python-parallelizing-cpu-bound-tasks-with-multiprocessing and reorganize my code. Both of them start from same method, but I avoid above problem though I still don't know why. Anyway, it works.